# Google Play Market Authentication for Symfony 3 app

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-play, symfony

How can I configure authentication and authorisation to my Symfony 3 app by Google Play Market Account? I tried to use [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle) for these purposes. The documentation tells to create a client using ClientManager in this way:

```
$clientManager = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default');
$client = $clientManager->createClient();
$client->setRedirectUris(array('http://www.example.com'));
$client->setAllowedGrantTypes(array('token', 'authorization_code'));
$clientManager->updateClient($client);
```

But no words, about where to put this code. But I am already have credentials which I got from Google Console. Is it possible to use them in order to login with Google Play Market account? How to bind them with custom authentication proWhere should I use these credintials? Are there any tutorials about this process in scope of Symfony 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FOSOAuthServerBundle` is a server. What you need is a client.

You should try to use [`HWIOAuthBundle`](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) instead or [`thephpleague/oauth2-client`](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client). If none of these libraries fit on your needs, you may find other implementations [on Packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=oauth2%20client).

Comment: HWIOAuthBundle is not compatible with Symfony 3.1 yet... what should I use indtead?